# How to print nth element in a PHP array/JSON object?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, math

I have some foreach loops because of a multidimensional array/JSON object. I am trying to print every nth element (5th element in this case) of the last foreach loop. I tried using modulus but wasn't successful.

```
foreach($data['data'] as $k1=>$v1) {
 foreach($v1['cars'] as $k2=>$v2) {
  $counter= 1
   foreach($v2['colours'] as $k3=>$v3) {


        if ($counter % 5 == 0) {
      print $v3; //print every 5th colour
      $counter++;
      }


    }
   }  
  }
```

Comment: Your counter only increase when you're on the fifth element... which you determine with the counter... so it never increases and you never reach the fifth count.

Comment: Also, pay attention of the missing ; at the end of the $counter = 1

Comment: Did you create an new account just because your previous question was a duplicate? It happens to everyone. I advice you to stick to one account from now on.

Answer (score 3):

Your counter needs to be outside the if statement

```
$counter = 1;
foreach($data['data'] as $k1=>$v1) {
   foreach($v1['cars'] as $k2=>$v2) {
      foreach($v2['colours'] as $k3=>$v3) {
         if ($counter % 5 == 0) {
            print $v3; //print every 5th colour

         }
         $counter++;
     }
  }  
}
```

The reason being that every time you execute the loop you want the counter to increment, rather than just incrementing when the condition is true

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can array_chunk $v2 on 5 and output only [0].

```
foreach($data['data'] as $k1=>$v1) {
 foreach($v1['cars'] as $k2=>$v2) {
   $temp = array_chunk($v2['colours'],5);
   foreach($temp as $val){
      echo $val[0];
   }
  }  
 }
```

This also iterates less than your method as it skips four out of five elements.

Short demo of what my code does: https://3v4l.org/GbU2T